Is there a language in which "K" comes first in alphabet?
Our instructor of a group project I was a part of has asked us to arrange the authors' names in alphabetical order. Since he hasn't specified which alphabetical order to use, and my name happens to start with a "K", I was just wondering, you know :)
Is there a language that starts its alphabet with "K", or something that sounds similar?

I am assuming this is purely a hypothetical, and you do not actually intend to make this argument to your instructor (as it would doubtless not be received in good humour).
Hangul (used in Korea) places its letter for /k/ first, although this is usually transliterated with <g>.
The Brahmic and Kana syllabaries (the former used across South and Southeast Asia, the latter in Japan) are syllabaries rather than alphabets, but do put their k-series ahead of all other consonant series (the vowel series does precede them though).
It's worth noting however that whilst alphabetical order can be taken to mean "the order of an alphabet", it can also be taken to mean "the order of the Alphabet" i.e. alpha, beta, etc. This order is inherited from the Phoenician alphabet that is the ancestor of the vast majority of alphabetic scripts in use today (and many ancient scripts as well). In this sense, "alphabetical order" would never place k first.
As this alphabetical order (sensu stricto) is inherited in the vast majority of alphabetical (sensu lato) scripts descended from Phoenician, it is unlikely to be worthwhile looking within that script family for further examples.

of course not! this question is purely hypothetical, partly a joke, and I don't plan to use it anywhere :) Associating authorship order to credit is meaningless anyway.

I was pretty certain that was the case, just thought it was important to state that upfront
